# If I don't use metamask who manages the private key and the incoming or outgoing ether?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, metamask, private-key

I want to build a dapp without using metamask but web3.js and a node (geth / parity). So if I use this second method what happens when ethere needs to be sent to an account?

Comment: "I want to build a dapp without using metamask" then it is just an app.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Maybe he's looking to use other providers but I would agree that it's ambiguos

Comment: @strangethingspy I read this article [link](https://medium.com/@mehradsadeghi/dapps-without-metamask-17528d14e3fa )and he doesn't seem to be making a wallet. I don't understand who manages the private key and ether in this case

Comment: That's definitely something that should not be done, he is just using his private key to send a transaction. If a user needs to interact with your contract he will have to send a tx from his address.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [a hot wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84401/how-to-build-an-ethereum-hot-wallet-for-an-exchange) for your users and then manage the funds on behalf of your users.

Comment: I read this article [link](https://medium.com/@mehradsadeghi/dapps-without-metamask-17528d14e3fa) and he doesn't seem to be making a wallet