# Metamask integration in platform with backend

Tags: metamask

Hi guys.

I have a platfrom. And I need.
When user deposit money they move using Metamask from user wallet to platform wallet and add to user balance in the platform.
When user withdraw money they move from platform wallet to user wallet and remove from user balance in the platform.

I don't understand, how can I make changes with user balance in my platform after Metamask transaction?

Comment: Please read https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/84401/620

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Thank you for you answer. For understanding. I have to create smart contract only, is it? Attack it to my address and when balance changed it send http request to my backend, right?